# Django foreign key new model instance used as default

Tags: python, django

I'm wondering whether it's possible to do something like the following

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    my_field = models.ForeignKey('UniqueKey', to_field='key' default=UniqueKey.create(key=KeyGen()))
    # KeyGen() returns a new random key
```

In essence, I have a number of models that have a unique 32 digit key as one of their fields. I have created the `UniqueKey` model to manage all of those keys and make sure no duplicates ever arise. What I'm trying to do is create a new `UniqueKey` instance and save it to the database whenever I make a new `ModelA` instance.

Is this possible or am I just going about this the wrong way?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye do you mean that it would be poor form to have a database entry which was like a catch all and then have the default for a foreign key be the id of that catch all entry?

Comment: It should work, if the default value is serializable at migration time. Have a look at this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/#serializing-values

Comment: @MosesKoledoye ahhhhhh, I forgot that the default value is actually going to be the default value in the database and that the database isn't going to know how to create a new model instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best approach will be to use the post_save signal when an instance of your model is created. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#post-save

i.e.

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    my_field = models.ForeignKey('UniqueKey', to_field='key')

def set_default_uniquekey_for_modela(sender, instance, created, raw, using, update_fields):
    if created is True:
        new_unique_key = UniqueKey(key=KeyGen())
        new_unique_key.save()
        instance.my_field = new_unique_key
        instance.save()

post_save.connect(set_default_uniquekey_for_modela, sender=ModelA)
```

So when an instance of ModelA is created, it will exectute `set_default_uniquekey_for_modela(...)` to create a new UniqueKey instance and assign that to the instance.